# Encoding of combination without and with repetition into binary string

Tags: combinatorics

**Combination with repetition**

How many positive integers solutions or null the equation $x + y + z = 8$ have?

$\{(x,y,z) |x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}, x + y + z = 8\}$

In order to find the cardinality of this set, I would simply have to encode a possible solution into a binary string as the following. Consider the solution $(2, 0, 6)$. It can be encoded as $11 0 0 111111$. There are 10 entries in total, but since I'm only interested at the 1's, the solution corresonds to $\binom{10}{8}$.

**Combination without repetition**

However, if we would consider the same problem except that we wouldn't want any repetition, how could this situation now be encoded into binary string.

Comment: "*Except we don't want any repetition.*"  To be clear, you mean you allow outcomes like $(2,0,6)$ and consider this a different outcome than $(6,2,0)$ but you do not allow outcomes like $(3,3,2)$ since the number $3$ appeared multiple times in the tuple?

Comment: The general problem is frustrating and doesn't have a clean closed form as I recall, but has a nice generating function.  The number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ distinct possibly empty parts will be $k!$ times the coefficient of $q^kx^n$ in the expansion of $\prod\limits_{i=0}^\infty (1+qx^i)$.  As for "*how could this be encoded into a binary string?*"  In exactly the same way.  It is just that some binary strings won't correspond to outcomes of the type you are interested in.